# Change input language separately in different applications like in windows

Tags: language-support

Lets say I have Firefox and my IDE opened. Input language is set to English.
Then I open chat in Firefox and change language to Russian.

Then I alt-tab to my IDE and have language set to Russian too. So language is changed system-wide.
What I want is to not change language in my IDE and keep it English.

Is it possible to have windows-like behavior: different languages for different applications?

Ubuntu version: 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: @pomsky typing. Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: Go to Settings -> Keyboard - > Text Entry  and check "allow different layouts for individual windows" option or something similar.